# In perl, How do i obtain the value of a hash, whose hash name is stored in a string?

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I am trying to read the value of a hash, whose name and index is stored in a string. I can only obtain the value if i hard-code the hash and its index but not if i take it from another variable. To describe it better i have mentioned the code below:

```
    use strict 'vars';
    #------------------------------

    # Hash to store some values
    our %SystemUser = (
                Username => "system",
                Password => "system"
    );

    # Prints successfully if i use the below technique
    print "Using Hard-Coding technique : ${SystemUser{'Password'}}\n";

    my $Reference = "SystemUser{'Password'}";

    # Doesn't print if i use this technique where $Reference contains the hash-index pair 
    print "Using Referencing technique : ${$Reference}\n";

    print "Reference value : $Reference\n";
```

I want to print the value of `SystemUser{'Password'}` using `${$Reference}` (having `$Reference = "SystemUser{'Password'}"` value)

Comment: Comments in Perl start with `#`, not `//`.

Comment: well, you can get the value with eval "\$$Reference"; but this is bad... Why do you have the name of the complete variable and hash key inside a string?

Comment: @jfried : I am making a code which has 0 hard-coding. This is a part of the code that i was doing to make my script 0 hard-coding. I was reading a file for parameter-value pairs so, i am obtaining that reference from a file. Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: What you are doing it called "templating". Use a proper template module.

Comment: `SystemUser{'Password'}` is not the name of a hash. `SystemUser` is.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you should avoid doing this as a technical approach.

If you need to obtain one of a set of hashes dynamically by name, the correct solution (pattern for those from Java world) is to store the hashes in a **hash of hashrefs**; with keys of the outer hash being what the individual hash names were supposed to be:

```
my %users = (
     SystemUser => {
            Username => "system",
            Password => "system"
     }
    ,GuestUser => {
            Username => "xxx",
            Password => "xxx"
     }

);
print "$users{SystemUser}->{Password}";
```

---

On a technical level, you can do that using a dereferencing construct `${$NAME}`

However, bear in mind that:

- **It is bad practice to do so.**

  Unless you have a very good technical reason why you can not sue a hash of hashrefs as above, do NOT do so.
- Under "`use strict`" (which you should ALWAYS use), you are not allowed to use strings as references at all:

  ```
  # WORKS without use strict
  $ perl -e 'our %h=(1=>2); print ${"h"}{1}' 

   2

  # use strict prohibits that:
  $ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; our %h=(1=>2); print ${"h"}{1}'
  Can't use string ("h") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use 

  # but you can unfix by relaxing "strict refs":
  perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; \
      { no strict "refs"; our %h=(1=>2); print ${"h"}{1}; use strict "refs";}'
   2
  ```

Comment: @Borodin - INFORMATION WANTS TO BE FREE! :)

Comment: @DVK - INFORMATION hates to be anthropomorphised

Answer (score 2):

`${}` can only return you the value itself - i.e. hash, index in next pair of `{}` must remain outside.

```
my $Reference = "SystemUser";
my $Field = 'Password';

print "Reference value : ${$Reference}{$Field}\n";
```

Still, accessing global variables by named reference is a bad practice in Perl. You're better off using hash of hashes.

Answer (score 1):

If by "0 hard coding" you mean that everything is parameterised, then you can't practically do that: the program has to make at least *some* assumptions

But it is practical to make most data configurable, although the way to do it isn't to store Perl code in a config file

```
SystemUser{'Password'}
```

is Perl code, and your config files should consist only of *data*

But you can write, for example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %config = (
    SystemUser => {
        Username => 'system',
        Password => 'system'
    }
);

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($domain, $field) = split;
    print "Value: $config{$domain}{$field}\n";
}
__DATA__
SystemUser Password
```

**output**

```
Value: system
```